# Footnotes, which follow citation numbering and only appear in the reference list (alongside references)

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, journal

I want my footnotes to only appear in my reference list, and have the same enumeration as my citations: In a matter of speaking, I want to mix references and footnotes. The footnotes are not supposed to appear at the bottom of the page where they were used, but only in the reference list.

I have attached a screenshot of a paper I am reading, where it seems to be the etiquette to do it that way (Physics Review B). Compare reference 18 and 19: 18 is a proper reference, while 19 is just the footnote text.

Can I somehow imitate this?

[image: Footnotes in reference list]

Comment: Use `endnotes` and then use a style which puts full references in footnotes. Then don't print a list of references at all, just print your endnotes. All footnotes will become endnotes, including the ones which contain references and the ones which contain notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick is, first, to use `endnotes`; second, to redefine `\footnote` to produce an endnote; and, third, to use a `verbose` citation style with `biblatex` rather than printing a separate list of references.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}

Here is some text with a footnote\footnote{First footnote.} and a reference to somebody\autocite{westfahl:space}. Here is another footnote\footnote{Second footnote.} and another citation\autocite{matuz:doody,}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: Endnotes with references]